# To display the details of the selected item in the listview control in a new page in Navigation apps of WinJS

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I am working in a grid (WinJS.UI.ListView technically) and when the user touches one of the tiles,I want to navigate to a second page with more details about that element. I am able to navigate to the different page but unable to get the details of the selected item

Comment: i have same problem ,  too. Inner element in Application.PageControlNavigator dont navigate self.

Answer (score 0):

The selected item is generally passed over as a parameter in the navigation.

So when you navigate to the details page you might use:

```
var item = Data.items.getAt(args.detail.itemIndex);
nav.navigate("/pages/itemDetail/itemDetail.html", { item: Data.getItemReference(item) });
```

And then in the details page you can access the options parameter that is passed to the ready function:

```
ready: function (element, options) {
    // The data you passed in will be in the options parameter
    var item = options && options.item ? Data.resolveItemReference(options.item) : Data.items.getAt(0);
}
```

You can learn more about WinJS navigation over on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738344.aspx